# What's going on behind this ghost edit

Tags: bug

On the hot page I noticed this :

[image]

Which I've already seen before but, it have been "modified" by a user which is not what I see when I go to the question : [Check Mac battery percentage in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29278961/2307070).

Usually I'd blame caching but here I can't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29279221/266143) is deleted by the answerer himself, Jordan. The "modified 3 mins ago" you see is cached.

Comment: Ok, so I was blaming the wrong page. And was not able to see this because I'm not (yet) 10k+. Thanks CC :)

Comment: @Thomas Looks like you can [blame caching](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/).

Comment: Now his answser (Jordan) is 23 min old. Delete/undelete ?

Comment: @Thomas yes, you can see that in the [edit history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29279221/revisions) now. :)